# $_POST variable is always the same

Tags: php, html, post

I'm trying to get a variable from a link (invisible button, basically), however, when I get to the redirected page, it's always the same $_POST variable it shows. I've checked if it's set before or after the for loop, and it's not. I've also printed out the values in the for loop, and they're different, as they should be. I've also tried unsetting the variable at the bottom of the redirect page after use. I'm totally out of ideas now... what to do?

```
<form method="post" action="http://localhost:8888/wordpress/job-openings/view-job/">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Job ID</th>
                        <th>Position</th>       
                        <th>Client</th>
                        <th>Recruiter</th>
                     </tr>
                        <? for($i = 0; $i < count($rowArray); $i++) { ?>
                            <? $positionStatus = $data->response->result->JobOpenings->row[$i]->FL[8]->content;
                               $recruitmentResponsible = $data->response->result->JobOpenings->row[$i]->FL[7]->content;
                               $recruitmentResponsibleTweak = current(explode("(", $recruitmentResponsible));
                               $job_opening_id = $data->response->result->JobOpenings->row[$i]->FL[0]->content;
                               $request_url = 'http://recruit.zoho.com/ats/private/json/JobOpenings/getRecordById?authtoken=xxx&scope=recruitapi&id=' . $job_opening_id;
                            if ($positionStatus == 'In-progress') {
                                ?>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <input type="hidden" name="job_id" value="<?php echo $request_url ?>" />
                                            <button id="jobopening-link">
                                                <? echo $data->response->result->JobOpenings->row[$i]->FL[4]->content; ?>
                                            </button>
                                    </td>
                                    <td><? echo $data->response->result->JobOpenings->row[$i]->FL[5]->content; ?></td>
                                    <td><? echo $data->response->result->JobOpenings->row[$i]->FL[6]->content; ?></td>
                                    <td><? echo $recruitmentResponsibleTweak ?></td>
                                </tr>
                            <? }
                        } ?>
                </table>
            </form>
```

Comment: can you post relevant code? because what you posted is not really helpful

Comment: *Rasmus Lerdorf, is that you? I hope not.*

Comment: I might be Rasmus Lerdorf.

Comment: @AlanMachado I sincerely doubt that. Check out PHP.net ;-) I doubt he needs to be taught, the *"real"* Rasmus that is. http://php.net/manual/en/history.php.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, there is no reference to `$_POST` in your code. Second, the reason why you get always the same value is because you are always setting the same exactly name to the hidden input, and when the form is sent you will get only the first input with that name. My suggestion, is to move the form tag inside the for loop, that way you will create multiple forms and each one will have the submit button and the proper value in the hidden input:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Job ID</th>
        <th>Position</th>
        <th>Client</th>
        <th>Recruiter</th>
    </tr>
    <? for($i = 0; $i < count($rowArray); $i++) { ?>
    <form method="post" action="http://localhost:8888/wordpress/job-openings/view-job/">
        <? $positionStatus = $data->response->result->JobOpenings->row[$i]->FL[8]->content;
        $recruitmentResponsible = $data->response->result->JobOpenings->row[$i]->FL[7]->content;
        $recruitmentResponsibleTweak = current(explode("(", $recruitmentResponsible));
        $job_opening_id = $data->response->result->JobOpenings->row[$i]->FL[0]->content;
        $request_url = 'http://recruit.zoho.com/ats/private/json/JobOpenings/getRecordById?authtoken=xxx&scope=recruitapi&id=' . $job_opening_id;
        if ($positionStatus == 'In-progress') {
        ?>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="hidden" name="job_id" value="<?php echo $request_url ?>" />
                <button id="jobopening-link">
                    <? echo $data->response->result->JobOpenings->row[$i]->FL[4]->content; ?>
                </button>
            </td>
            <td><? echo $data->response->result->JobOpenings->row[$i]->FL[5]->content; ?></td>
            <td><? echo $data->response->result->JobOpenings->row[$i]->FL[6]->content; ?></td>
            <td><? echo $recruitmentResponsibleTweak ?></td>
        </tr>

        <? } ?>
    </form>
    <? } ?>
</table>
```

Comment: Yes! Of course I just had to move it into the loop. Thanks. But why do you say there is no reference to $_POST in my code? Is it not enough to specify the method of the form?

Answer (score 0):

and the input type="submit"???

to capture the $_POST content:

```
<?php 
if (isset($_POST['job_id'])) {
echo 'Do something for this job Id.';
}
?>
```